# What exactly is Z axis in CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical, and does X axis change as per the motion of the user?

Tags: ios, core-motion

I am using core motion to get device motions running the project on an iPod touch 3. The CMAttitudeReferenceFrame used in my method - (void)startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:(CMAttitudeReferenceFrame)referenceFrame toQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue withHandler:(CMDeviceMotionHandler)handler is CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical.
As per the documentation, it describes a reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points in an arbitrary direction in the horizontal plane. When the device is resting still on the table, with its screen facing upwards, the gravity from cmdevicemotion reads around -1, which is right. But, when I turn over the phone by 90 degrees such that the vector normal to the screen points towards me, the values for gravity along Z nowhere shows around -1. I thought that the Z axis will remain in the vertical direction pointing towards the earth. Or is it that the Z axis is fixed along the normal to the screen?
Also, if I am walking around with the device in hand such that the normal to the screen is along the direction of earth's gravity, and then after some time, give the device some yaw, say 45 degrees, will the arbitrary X axis of CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical still point in the direction of my unidirectional motion(which is x in my frame of ref)?

What if the user does not go in a straight line, for example if I am moving in a circle, will the arbitrary X axis using ref frame CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical (or CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical) be directed tangentially to the circle, like my circular motion velocity, in two situations:
1. If I hold the device such that the normal vector to the screen coincides with the direction of gravity pointing towards the earth, with the default Y axis along the plane of the device, pointing in teh direction of my motion, being tangential to the circle while I move along its circumference
2. Without the above restriction of not changing the spatial orientation of the device in my ref frame, I am just toying around with the device causing it to be in different arbitrary orientations, while I move along the circumference